# Get a Facebook event page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I was working with FB API and FQL to get some event codes of an indentified user.

But I want to show the Facebook event page, but I cannot find the way to do it...

Here an example:

```
I go to mywebsite.com, and I login into Facebook.
I get a list of all my current events, with a Link
If I follow this link, I get the event ID (1234567, for example)
[this step is the one I want to do]:
I show in my website (like if it was an iframe) the following FB page:
    https://www.facebook.com/events/1234567
```

So, with that I want to allow the users to interact directly with facebook, but without leaving my website...

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible. Facebook does not allow you to put their website into a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
function viewFBActivity($id){
    $h = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/events/".$id."/");
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $ret= curl_exec($h);
    echo($ret);
}
```

I hope it helps someone in the future!